# java keystore and password security for smartcard on windows

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

In the code below password is requested to the user by the java application:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = getPassword();
java.io.FileInputStream fis =
    new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
ks.load(fis, password);
fis.close();
```

Does it mean the application could get my digital certificate password even if it is on a smartcard  and potentially use it for something else ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question... but yes, if a user provides a password to a given application, the app can do whatever it wants. As always, if you provide a password to a system, it's on you to decide whether to trust the app or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, another application with sufficient privileges could read the contents of the password from memory or snoop the password as it is typed into the keyboard.

The code example shows the password stored as a `char` array, which is recommended practice. Such arrays can be reset to a different value after the password is used, unlike immutable `String`s. This minimises the attack window, but does not remove it.

Several smart card manufacturers offer external PIN pad devices that ensure the password is delivered directly to the card. You could consider investigating one of these solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that an usb token with smartcard allows password to be stored in memory ? That would be weird: image an app allows to send money ... :)

Comment: @user310291 In the code fragment you shared above, then yes - the password is (no doubt briefly) stored in memory. The solution is still an improvement on simply password-based security, as the attacked would need access to the smart card in addition to stealing the password.